# kitkat version to play a video in fullscreen

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this in my code already and setting the layout width and height in the ui xml file to fill parent but still does not stretch to fit the width

***Other version it works fine but not for kitkat version***

```
        VideoView video;
        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        video.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logoa);
        video.setVideoPath(strPath);      
        tracker.trackPageView("Video-"+SplitString(strPath));
        video.start();
        video.requestFocus();
```

please help me how to play it in kitkat version